# My div slider isn't pulling in the inside divs

Tags: jquery, slider

**Javascript:**

```
function Slider() {
    $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 500);
    var sc = $(".slider div").size();
    var count = 2;
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".slider #" + count).show("slide", {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500);
        $(".slider #" + count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 500);
        if (count == sc) {
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }, 6500);
}​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slider">
  <div id="1" style="position:relative">
    <img src=". .  ." />
    <div>
      <p style="width:350px; position:absolute; top:100px; left:10px">TEXT . .  .</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" style="position:relative">
    <img src=". .  ." />
    <div>
      <p style="width:350px; position:absolute; top:100px; left:10px">TEXT . .  .</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" style="position:relative">
    <img src=". .  ." />
    <div>
      <p style="width:350px; position:absolute; top:100px; left:10px">TEXT . .  .</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I am trying to do a slider.  I have the imgaes working just fine, but I wanted to do CSS text over top of the images.  When I run the script it doesn't pull the text divs in.  It just pulls the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/KzeMg/

Comment: You'll probably want to create a jsFiddle or post a link to an example, and at a minimum post your HTML.

Comment: I am trying to get the code in the box it just wants to be stubborn :-/

Comment: There you go i hope that helps

Comment: Probably not the complete problem but I know those ID's don't look right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: I think I will scrap it and find a different tutorial to follow lol

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do but there is certainly an easier way / existing plugin to use. Take a look at jqueryui.